# Keras basic example not improving

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I tried to build a very simple keras model. There is only 1 feature and data looks like this:

```
[[1.39e+05 4.50e+01]
 [1.72e+05 4.30e+01]
 [2.49e+05 8.70e+01]
 ...
```

I split into train/test and normalize:

```
mean = data.mean(axis=0)
std = data.std(axis=0)

train = data[:800].astype('float64')
test = data[801:].astype('float64')

x_train = (train[:, 1] - mean[1]) / std[1]
y_train = (train[:, 0] - mean[0]) / std[0]

x_test = (test[:, 1] - mean[1]) / std[1]
y_test = (test[:, 0] - mean[0]) / std[0]
```

This is my training:

```
model = models.Sequential()

model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu', input_dim=1))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 20, verbose = 2, validation_data = (x_test, y_test))
```

The model does not improve, the predictions are way off. Where is my problem? Here is the output from the training process:

```
rain on 800 samples, validate on 248 samples
Epoch 1/20
 - 0s - loss: 0.8860 - mean_absolute_error: 0.6731 - val_loss: 0.5488 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.5976
Epoch 2/20
 - 0s - loss: 0.7370 - mean_absolute_error: 0.6315 - val_loss: 0.4969 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.5837
Epoch 3/20
 - 0s - loss: 0.6765 - mean_absolute_error: 0.6154 - val_loss: 0.4804 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.5730
Epoch 4/20
 - 0s - loss: 0.6538 - mean_absolute_error: 0.6079 - val_loss: 0.4730 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.5664
Epoch 5/20
 - 0s - loss: 0.6326 - mean_absolute_error: 0.6049 - val_loss: 0.4689 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.5632
Epoch 6/20
 - 0s - loss: 0.6297 - mean_absolute_error: 0.6053 - val_loss: 0.4834 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.5671
Epoch 7/20
 - 0s - loss: 0.6226 - mean_absolute_error: 0.6066 - val_loss: 0.4721 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.5627
Epoch 8/20
 - 0s - loss: 0.6189 - mean_absolute_error: 0.6055 - val_loss: 0.4964 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.5732
Epoch 9/20
```

Comment: Increase the learning rate by: `from keras import optimizers` and then `model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-2), ...)` or use `1e-1`. Report back the result, please.

Comment: Thank you. Changing the learning rate indeed helped. I know think that because the data is so simple that the model just converged very fast, which lead to no visible progress in the epochs after epoch 3.

Comment: That's right. Since in this case the mapping (from x to y) is simple and there are (relatively) high number of parameters in the model, then choosing a small learning rate just slows down the progress.

Comment: @today What about reducing the number of parameters in the model? Simple model for simple problem?

Comment: @VikasNS Yes, that's another approach. As I mentioned in my comment the number of parameters is (relatively) high.

Comment: @today I didn't understand how increasing the learning rate can solve this problem? Could you please give a little more detailed explanation.

Comment: @VikasNS Since the underlying mapping function is a simple one, then by using lots of parameters you are essentially making it harder to find; because the training process needs to tune lots of parameters and search for a solution in a relatively high-dimensional space. Therefore, a low learning rate slows down this search. It forces the learning algorithm to be very cautious and take small steps. Since we know the problem is an easy one and surely a solution can be found in this high dimensional space, we increase the learning rate to let the model to take, say more courageous steps.